# Clean up unused pods before summiting app

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I noticed that my app folder uses 1.1Mb, and my pods folder uses 109Mb. My app uses some pods functionality, but defiantly not all code in pods is used. So my question is - will Xcode reduce/optimise app size before submitting app to AppStore? If not, how could I optimise myself?

Comment: So your asking if you can remove parts of a certain pod for optimisation? This does not sound like a good idea. Any pods you might have and are using in your project should be treated as a 'black box', and should not be modified directly.

Comment: Basically my question is if there is some code/functions that are not used in my (and there is), how should I delete/clean them in order to reduce final app size?
And I have not published any app yet, so maybe Xcode does that automatically?

Comment: To answer your question. Should you modify any pods currently in use in your project? No. Should you remove pods which you are not using? Yes. Remove them from the Podfile and run `pod install`. No, Xcode does not do any kind of optimization for you in terms of removing unused code.

Comment: Currently all of installed pods are used, I do realise that I should uninstall unused pods and should not modify pods on my own. However my project folder still uses 110Mb of which only 1.1Mb is my actual code (I do realise my actual code is also using part of 109Mb (pods codes), but defiantly not all). What can be done to optimise app size?

Comment: 110Mb is nothing. A compiled archive (the file you actually submit to Apple) of your project will probably come down to 20-30Mb.

Comment: Great, that was exactly what I wanted to know (if final product, that user will download will be as big as my current project folder)

Comment: You can easily test this right now by doing 'Product > Archive' and then inspect the binary in Finder to see how many Mb it is.

Comment: I did 'Product > Archive' and my '.xarchive' uses 145Mb, so even more than my project folder, I think I am doing something very wrong?

Comment: That doesn't make a whole lot of sense. I checked out some more of our projects and they are all smaller in archived form (most of them drastically smaller; half the size or less). Your app must use a lot of image resources(?). Still, this doesn't explain why your archive is larger in size than your actual project.

Comment: This is interesting, though. I'd really like to know what's causing this. So please answer your own question here on SO if you can figure this out.